# Pass session data from laravel controller to vuejs template

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

Is there anyway I can pass session data from my laravel controller to a .vue file?

Please help.

PS: I am using laravel 5.4 and vuejs 2

Answer (score 2):

You can pass strings and colllections to vue from blade templates like so:

```
<my-component :collection="{!! $collection->toJson() !!}" string=" {{ $string }}"></my-component>
```

Just remember to add the corresponding props to your `MyComponent.vue` file.

```
props: ['collection', 'string']
```

So more specifically if you intend to use a the values from Laravel `session('key', 'default')` then you have to be sure that you know whether you need to json encode an object or array or if you are passing just a string value.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to construct a method from your controller and ajax request it and catch him from vue method.

Example:
from your controller :

```
 function mysession(){
 return session()->all()}
```

from your vue will like this like call this method when mounted() or ready

```
 var self = this
 $.get('mysession',function(response) {
 self.sessionsData = response; }
```

after this execution sessionsData will now hold your sessions objects came from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

### Pass session data from Laravel to Vue

I had the same problem; unfortunately, I couldn't pass the session data from a controller, but managed to pass session data in another way.

**NOTE:** I used Laravel 9 and Vue 3

Add the following to your router/web.php file; in this case, I'm returning an array that contains a user id and username taken from the current session.

```
Route::get('session', function () {
return [
    'user_id' => session()->get('account_id'),
    'username' => session()->get('username')
];});
```

Afterwards, put the following in your Example.vue's script tag and use the 'session' variable however you like.

```
data: function() {
return {session: []}
},
mounted(){
this.loadSession
},
methods:{
loadSession: function (){
        axios.get('session')
            .then( (response) => {
                this.session = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error){
                console.log(error);
            });
    },
}
```

Quick explanation of the code:

1. Declare the session variable
2. Once the vue component has been mounted, call the loadSession() function
3. Use axios to get the data being returned from route/web.php/'session' and store the response in the session variable

This may not be the best solution, but it works. There might be a better solution out there though.